# Bootstrap 3 selected tab background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, background-color

I have a bootstrap 3 Top navigation bar with the following code and tabs:

```
<div class="tabbable" style="background:#85131a; font-family:'Franklin Gothic Book'">
<!--container-->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Top Menu</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="selectedtab">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size: 16px; color:white; font-family:'Franklin Gothic Book'">
        <li>
            <a style="color:white; line-height:40px;" href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/ %>" runat="server">START</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="color:white; line-height:40px;" href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab1/ %>" runat="server">Tab 1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab1/dd1/ %>" runat="server">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab1/dd2/ %>" runat="server">Dropdown item 2</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="color:white; line-height:40px;" href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab2/ %>" runat="server">Tab 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab2/dd1 %>" runat="server">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab2/dd2 %>" runat="server">Dropdown item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab2/dd3 %>" runat="server">Dropdown item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="color:white; line-height:40px;" href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab3/ %>" runat="server">Tab 3</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab3/dd1 %>" runat="server">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab3/dd2 %>" runat="server">Dropdown item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/tab3/dd3 %>" runat="server">Dropdown item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>                                                                    
</div>
<!--container-->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#selectedtab ul li a').click(function (ev) {
    $('#selectedtab ul li').removeClass('selected');
    $(ev.currentTarget).parent('li').addClass('selected');
});
});
```

CSS (besides all the bootstrap standard css) :

```
#selectedtab ul li.selected {
background-color:green !important;
}
```

My question is how to get the selected tab (From Tab 1, Tab 2 or Tab 3) with a different background color? It should change background-color depending on the selected tab.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle showing your issue?

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/ZccZF/

Answer (score 0):

Try the CSS:

.#selectedtab ul li:nth-child(2) {background-color:#FF0000;} .#selectedtab ul li:nth-child(3) {background-color:#336699;}

ANd so on :)

Above is not supported by IE 8 and earlier.

If you also want to support the IE 8 and earlier, you have to give each tab another class and define the background for each of those classes:

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

But what happens now is that the second and the third tab always have another background color, even if I haven't selected a tab. Could a solution be something with the URL and JavaScript to use a if statement?